# Store won't pass shipping address to Paypal Express

Tags: expresso-store, paypal

**Paypal**  won't help as they say it's a **Store** issue, but I'm struggling to get Store to send the shipping address details to Paypal.

The billing address is coming through fine, but the shipping address isn't. This is necessary for my client to retain their Paypal seller protection. If the address is not passed through seller protection is lost.

It is also obviously annoying as they have to fill in details manually to print postage labels etc.

version is 2.1

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Is this PayPal Pro? Standard?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, Standard Paypal using Paypal Express API. Would upgrading to Pro fix this?  Paypal support were really aggressively unhelpful on the phone on the basis that this was a 3rd party issue with passing the details across from the site to them.

Comment: I have no idea. Just know that they are different gateways in Store, so someone answering would need to know in order to answer the question.

Comment: Can you please email support@exp-resso.com to follow up on this? We will probably need to make some changes on your server and test whether they trigger seller protection.

Comment: Hi Adrian, my client is also having this problem. If you resolved this issue for Jeremy,  please post the solution if it's generic enough to be helpful for others. Thanks